# Replace image/texture option not available?

Tags: texturing, image, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

I'm watching a tutorial on how to make Minecraft animations, and one step was to click on the replace a image button but it wouldn't let me.

[image]

Why is this option grayed out?

Comment: Welcome to the site, David. You might edit your post to include a link to the video tutorial you were following, and post a copy of your blend file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) which would provide those who wish to help more information about the situation.